Why does `chrome.tabs.create` create a tab and make it active even though active: false is being passed on mobile Chromium browsers?
I'm working on an MV3 Chromium extension. Within the extension, I need to create a new tab (doing so with the use of chrome.tabs.create) and navigate the user to a specific site. I want the new tab to open in the background so that the currently active tab doesn't change.
On the desktop Chrome browser, this functionality works fine. However, on mobile Chromium-based browsers that support extensions, such as the Kiwi browser, the tab that is supposed to open in the background steals focus and moves to the foreground.
How can I overcome this issue?
chrome.tabs.create({ url, active: false, pinned: false, selected: false });

Sounds like a mobile Chrome bug to me. Perhaps report it to the Kiwi developers.

You can switch back to the original tab using chrome.tabs.update:
// Save the current tab ID for later use
const [currentTab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true })

// Your actions to open a new tab
chrome.tabs.create({ url, active: false, pinned: false, selected: false })
...

// Switch back to the original tab
await chrome.tabs.update(currentTab.id, {active: true})


I had this problem with my extension on PC. The tab is always opened and activated. Turned out to be the browser setting  problem. The browser (not chrome, but with chrome kernel) had settings: always open new foreground tab when click link/ using super drag. Turn that off and it worked fine.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
